# Scala Splat inner workings

Tags: scala, splat

I know in scala I can say

```
def foo(x: Int*) ...

foo(Seq(1,2,3): _*)
```

But I can't say

```
foo(Seq(1,2,3))
```

So there must be some implicit conversion going on. What is this implicit conversion? What is the actual method that makes this happen. Or, if I'm wrong, how does it actually work?

Comment: The `_*` construct is discussed in [section 4.6.3 of the language spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html). There's no mention of implicit conversion. Also, the [`predef` source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/Predef.scala) has only one `_*` reference, where it is used, not defined. I suspect that it's just baked into the language, sort of like a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion when you use `Seq` with the type annotation `_*`, because a repeated parameter is basically a `Seq` already.

However, if you used an `Array`, then there would be an implicit conversion, and

```
foo(Array(1,2,3): _*)
```

would be

```
foo(wrapIntArray(Array(1,2,3)):_*)
```

`wrapIntArray` is an implicit function defined in `Predef`.

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): ArraySeq.ofInt
```

As to why the latter one (without the type annotation) is not accepted, I'm guessing it's just a design choice not to puzzle the developer on how it worked :).